# Efficiently building a pandas dataframe row by row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've been building pandas dataframes recently by iterating through multiple files, rows, etc. I've been building them by appending items in a dictionary and then converting to a dataframe:

I understand there are other tools such as apply() and interrows() to step through rows and apply or screen data by row. That is not the topic of this question.

```
new_data_dict = {}
for r in df.index:
    new_data = df.loc[r] **2
    new_data_dict[r] = new_data

new_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(new_data_dict, orient = 'index')
```

Is this the most efficient way to build a pandas df? I haven't compared it to pandas.DataFrame.append. I've had two thoughts about append. On one hand seems unnecessarily heavy to create a dataframe or series (of a single row) only to append it. On the otherhand everything built into pandas is super fast such as the above methods apply() and iterrows() as well as groupby() etc.

What is the 'pandamic' way to build a dataframe row by row?

Comment: For your case `new_df = df**2` would be probably more efficient and for sure much more readable.

Comment: please never use "pandamic" ever again

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the for loop and repeating the rows, you can use numpy.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'Location':['New York','Florida','California', 'Nevada','Georgia'],
                   'Owner':['John','Gary','Mike','Kate','Lucy'],
                   'Score':[50,80,70,90,80]})

print (df)
new_df = pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(df.values,2,axis=0))
print (new_df)
```

Original dataframe:

```
     Location Owner  Score
0    New York  John     50
1     Florida  Gary     80
2  California  Mike     70
3      Nevada  Kate     90
4     Georgia  Lucy     80
```

New Dataframe with repeated rows:

```
            0     1   2
0    New York  John  50
1    New York  John  50
2     Florida  Gary  80
3     Florida  Gary  80
4  California  Mike  70
5  California  Mike  70
6      Nevada  Kate  90
7      Nevada  Kate  90
8     Georgia  Lucy  80
9     Georgia  Lucy  80
```

Comment: Thanks! Gave this a +1 but not the correct answer for the question. You solve the specific example more efficiently but your answer could not be generalized if I wanted to do other operations or modify columns or values.

Comment: If you have additional things you need to add, let me know and the solution can be expanded. The question I saw was to find an efficient way to repeat rows. If you want to modify columns or do other things, it can be done with np.repeat.